# How do I prove that if two sets are homeomorphic, then the two sets have an equal number of isolated points?

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that if two sets are homeomorphic, then they have the same number of isolated points. I've been told a hint that I need to show that there is a bijection between the sets of non-isolated points to do this.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that the term "number" here should be construed as "cardinality", in case there is an infinite number

Answer (score 2):

Being isolated is a property defined only in terms of open sets, so if $f$ is the homeomorphism, then $x$ is isolated if and only if $f(x)$ is. Thus, $f$ induces a bijection between the isolated point sets.

Comment: So, to be more explicit, how would I prove that there is the same number of points? I was thinking on the lines of showing that there is a bijection between the limit points of the two sets but not sure how id go about? thanks.

Comment: The sets of isolated points are in bijection, which means they have the same number of points.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then it is an open map. Let $x\in U\in \tau_X$ such that $U\cap \{x\}=\{x\}.$ As $f\upharpoonleft U$ is bijective and open $f(U)$ is open and $f(U)\cap \{f(x)\}=\{f(x\},$ which shows $f(x)$ is isolated. To finish, apply the same reasoning to $f^{-1}.$